# Pilha em Java intercalando valores

Tags: java, stack

tenho duas pilhas tenho que criar a terceira intercalando os valores da duas pilhas criei a pilha e tudo so  que estou tendo um bloqueio para implementar o codigo para intercalar

segue o codigo:

```
public class Pilha {
    private Stack p;

    public Pilha()
    {
       p = new Stack();
    }

    public void insere(int x)
    {
        p.push(x);
    }

    public int remove()
    {
        return (int) p.pop();
        }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    int a=2, b=3, c=4, d=5,e=6,f=7,g=8,h=9;
    Pilha p1 = new Pilha();
    Pilha p2 = new Pilha();
    Pilha p3 = new Pilha();
    p1.insere(a);
    p1.insere(b);
    p1.insere(c);
    p1.insere(d);
    p2.insere(e);
    p2.insere(f);
    p2.insere(g);
    p2.insere(h);
```

Comment: Desculpe, não entendi mt bem o que quis dizer com "bloqueio", poderia me explicar?

Comment: Olá, @user3652472! Sua pergunta foi fechada pela comunidade porque com os dados fornecidos não é possível dar uma resposta clara e objetiva. Não conseguimos entender exatamente o problema. Porém, você pode editar sua pergunta adicionando logs, mensagens de erro, o código do aplicativo e algo que torne possível alguém respondê-la. Fique também à vontade para criar novas perguntas ou mesmo responder, mas sugiro ler sobre [como fazer uma boa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) na nossa [Central de Ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize uma variável de controle pra determinar de qual pilha você deve tirar o elemento. Algo como:

```
int pilha = 1;
if (pilha == 1) {
    p3.insere(p1.remove());
    pilha = 2;
}
else {
    p3.insere(p2.remove());
    pilha = 1;
}
```

Tenta utilizar essa idéia com um loop enquanto uma das pilhas tiver um elemento. Também implemente um método pra descobrir quando a pilha está vazia, vai ajudar.